# If i believe Islam, should i avoid soy sauce?

Tags: alcohol

Soy sauce include **alcohol**, but i heard:

> Even if we eat including alcohol meals, we can eat if we will not get drunk.

If i believe Islam, should i avoid soy sauce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this site](http://www.jhalal.com/info/1206.html) (Japanese), Japan Halal Association proposed to JAKIM because soy sauce does ***not*** include **khamar** (dirty alcohol). After that, it was accepted. So i do **not** need to avoid soy sauce.